# How to extract datetime object from string using regex in dart?

Tags: regex, string, dart

```
  final exp = RegExp(
    '^([1-9]|([012][0-9])|(3[01])) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d\d\d\d (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]?\ds+');
```

My input string is **14 Aug 2020 12:20,14 Aug 2020 12:20:30**

I need to convert the above string value to date and time, Please help. I tried using the above code but I'm stuck in somewhere

Comment: Is it a requirement to use a regex? You could properly do this much easier by using the intl package.

Comment: could you provide some examples

Answer (score 0):

Something like this using the `intl` package:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  const input = "14 Aug 2020 12:20,14 Aug 2020 12:20:30";
  input.split(',').map(parseDateTime).forEach(print);
  // 2020-08-14 12:20:00.000
  // 2020-08-14 12:20:30.000
}

DateTime parseDateTime(String input) {
  try {
    return DateFormat('dd MMM y HH:mm:ss').parse(input);
  } on FormatException {
    return DateFormat('dd MMM y HH:mm').parse(input);
  }
}
```

You can read more about the DateFormat class here: https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html